# Exclude one character, exclude one space, then 4 spaces

Tags: regex

I want to match this: exclude one character, exclude one space, then 4 spaces

here is what I tried but does not work

```
[^a-z0-9]{1}[^ ]{1}[ ]{4}
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tc4vWoxMPK4SiZ9b)

I just want the 4 spaces, but before those 4 spaces there should be one character and one space, I don't know if I can

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to match?

Comment: please name some examples, what should match and what not

Comment: arg @TomWyllie you beat me to it

Comment: I want to match this for example "t     " the 4 spaces after the t and the space

Comment: Please, edit your question and add some test cases.

Comment: @benaze your expression can't match first "t" - first class, `[^a-z0-9]`, matches **anything but** lowercase letters and digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches four spaces if they're preceeded by a lowercase letter/digit and one space.

```
(?<=[a-z0-9] ) {4}
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/faKn0P/1)

Comment: thanks but that's not what I want, I don't know if regex can match what I want, I just want the 4 spaces, but before those 4 spaces there should be one character and one space

Comment: @benaze understood you, that is called *lookbehind*. Editing answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand your need, this will do the job:

```
(?<=\w ) {4}
```

This is matching 4 spaces preceeded by an alphanumeric character and a space

Answer (score 0):

You wrote *exclude*, but I suppose you want to:

- skip one char (a letter of number),
- skip one space (after the just mentioned letter),
- skip (or maybe catch) another 4 spaces,
- catch the rest of the source text.

If this is the case, use the following regex:

```
[a-z0-9] ([ ]{4})(.*)
```

The four spaces (after initial char and space) will be in capture group #1
and the *rest of the text* will be in capture group #2.

Answer (score 0):

For increased portability (look-behinds aren't supported everywhere), readability, and simplicity, try this regex.

`(?:\w\s)(\s{4})`

The first matching group will be your spaces as desired.